# Does coc.nvim require Python?

Tags: neovim

The [installation instructions](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Install-coc.nvim) don't mention the need for Python or specific Python plugins. Although when I add coc.nvim to my vim plugs (`Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}`), install and restart Neovim, I get the following error:

```
[coc.nvim] Error on execute python script: request error nvim_command - Vim(pyxfile):E319: No "python3" provider found. Run ":checkhealth provider"
```

I'm a long time VIM/Neovim user and have my fair share of plugins installed, none of them has any dependency on 3rd party Python scripts, and I would like to keep it that way.

So my question is, does coc.nvim require Python or is there something misconfigured on my end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using https://github.com/neoclide/coc-snippets , which will load and parse Ultisnips snippets, some snippets need Python to run.

You can disable Python by setting `"snippets.ultisnips.usePythonx": false` in your coc-settings.json.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but currently I'm not using `coc-snippets`, only these: `Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release', 'do': ':CocInstall coc-solargraph coc-tsserver coc-eslint coc-json coc-css'}`. Unfortunately setting `snippets.ultisnips.usePythonx` to `false` also does not work.

Comment: Does `:CocList extensions` has coc-snippets?

Comment: Yes, coc-snippets was installed … weird. Manually removed it, now I don't get that an error on startup anymore. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using `"snippets.ultisnips.usePythonx": false` and running `pip install neovim` in my virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by `pip3 install --user pynvim`